# How to overlay a RGB ROI on top of a Greyscale Image in a GUIDE Axes?

Tags: matlab, overlay, rgb, roi

I am trying to figure out how to overlay a RGB ROI on top of a Greyscale image. I am able to accomplish this using a figure.

Here is my code for accomplishing this.

```
        mask=map>0;%map is the ROI

        im =im2double(dicomImage);
        im=gray2ind(double(im)/max(im(:)),128);

        h=subimage(im);
        set(h,'AlphaData',mask);
        imagesc(map);colormap(jet);colorbar; vvv=caxis;
        hold on;
        h=subimage(im);
        caxis(vvv);
        set(h,'AlphaData',~mask);
```

I would like to do the same thing within my GUI axes. If only an Axes had an 'AlphaData' property.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I can just set the focus to my axes than run this code. As such

```
    axes(handles.axes1);
```

After doing so some of my properties of my axes are going to be changed. So I have to reset my axes if I don't want an overlay. I also have to change the properties Position and Units as they don't default upon resetting the axes.

```
    cla(handles.axes1,'reset');
    set(handles.axes1,'Position',[5.2 1.4615384615384617 89.4 36.23076923076924]);  %hardcoded values for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to just create a temporary overlay image, using [imoverlay](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10502-image-overlay), and then display that, rather than messing with axis properties?